# Двойные кавычки в C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте всем, скажите как сделать чтобы консоль вывел такое : "Здорова", т.е с двойными кавычками.... пробовал так:

```
Console.Write("\"Здорова"\");
```

Но второй слеш стал черным и компилятор заругался. Как исправить?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Console.Write(@"""Здорова""");
```

или

```
Console.Write("\"Здорова\"");
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.